# Have a notification window similar to Windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

I want to have a notification window similar to windows 8 how it darts out from the side. I have tried implementing it like this however my thickness animation does not seem to be working.

```
<Window x:Class="URM.Views.DesktopAlert"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DesktopAlert" Height="184" Width="404" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" ShowActivated="False" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid  >

        <!-- Notification area -->
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFF0F0F0" BorderBrush="Transparent" CornerRadius="0">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="144" Width="385">
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF5C5C5C" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,29,0,0" Name="rectangle6" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="382" />
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Book" FontSize="17" Foreground="#FFF0F0F0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,30,10,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="{Binding NewAlert.AlertHeader}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333" TextAlignment="Right" />
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Book" FontSize="17" Foreground="#FF5C5C5C" Height="57" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,56,7,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding NewAlertText}" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <Button Content="X" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,-2,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="14" Foreground="#FF5C5C5C" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#FFF0F0F0" BorderThickness="0" Click="button1_Click" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                <TextBlock Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,8,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="ULTRA ROUTE MANAGEMENT" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF5C5C5C" />
                <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="195,121,0,0" Name="textBlock4" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="{Binding NewAlert.AlertLinkId}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" Foreground="#FF5C5C5C" FontSize="18"><TextBlock.TextDecorations><TextDecoration Location="Underline" /></TextBlock.TextDecorations></TextBlock>
                <Button Height="30" Content="{Binding NewAlert.AlertLinkId}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="182,113,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" FontSize="18" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Click="button2_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <!-- Animation -->
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Margin)" Duration="0:0:20" From="1900,200,0,0" To="1400,200,0,0"/>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Completed="DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames_Completed">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:15" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't see why the thickness animation wont work.

Comment: You want a Windows 8 style toast notification in a desktop app?

Comment: yes - just the appearance of one - a quick message that darts out from the right side of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation values are not proper it seems. I have tried with following code

```
<Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Margin)" Duration="0:0:20" From="518,3,-518,-3" To="0"/>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" >
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:15" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
```

it works fine for me.
In design view drag your grid out of window and you can get correct From value updated in grid's margin.

Comment: life saver - idk but I just couldn't figure this one out!

Comment: Open your MainWindow.xaml file and click design view at bottom of page. Select the grid and just drag out of window. Now switch to xaml view you will get margin updated in xaml use it...:)